# Room: Database not created

Tags: android, android-room

I try use room library from google architecture. I write few codes based on the BasicSample from google, but database not created (for my code). Logcat does not contains errors and exceptions. Please help me find my mistake:

```
//App.java
//...
public class App extends Application {
    private AppExecutors mAppExecutors;
    private static final String TAG = "App";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: enter");
        mAppExecutors = new AppExecutors();
        getDatabase();
    }

    public AppDatabase getDatabase() {
        return AppDatabase.getInstance(this, mAppExecutors);
    }
}
```

My AppDatabase class looks:

```
//AppDatabase.java
//...
@Database(entities = {Camera.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase";
    private static AppDatabase sInstance;
    private AppExecutors mExecutors;
    public abstract CameraDao cameraModel();

    public static AppDatabase getInstance(final Context context, final AppExecutors executors) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            synchronized (AppDatabase.class) {
                if (sInstance == null) {
                    sInstance = buildDatabase(context.getApplicationContext(), executors);
                }
            }
        }
        return sInstance;
    }
    private static final String TAG = "AppDatabase";
    private static AppDatabase buildDatabase(final Context context, final AppExecutors executors) {
        Log.i(TAG, "buildDatabase: enter");
        AppDatabase database = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME)
                .addCallback(new Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: ");
                        super.onCreate(db);

                        executors.diskIO().execute(() -> getInstance(context, executors).initDb());
                    }
                })
                .build();
        database.mExecutors = executors;
        Log.i(TAG, "buildDatabase: exit");
        return database;
    }

    private void initDb() {
        cameraModel().insert(new Camera(1, "Canon", "EOS 5d Mark III", 1024, 768, 24, 22, 0.0, true));
    }
}
```

Dao interface:

```
//CameraDao.java
@Dao
public interface CameraDao {
    @Insert
    void insert(Camera camera);
}
```

And Entity class:

```
// Camera.java
@Entity
public class Camera {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public long id;
    public String list_name;
    public String camera_name;
    public int max_resolution_width;
    public int max_resolution_height;
    public int max_sensor_width;
    public int max_sensor_height;
    public double coc;
    public boolean is_auto_coc;

    public Camera(long id, String list_name, String camera_name, int max_resolution_width, int max_resolution_height, int max_sensor_width, int max_sensor_height, double coc, boolean is_auto_coc) {
        this.id = id;
        this.list_name = list_name;
        this.camera_name = camera_name;
        this.max_resolution_width = max_resolution_width;
        this.max_resolution_height = max_resolution_height;
        this.max_sensor_width = max_sensor_width;
        this.max_sensor_height = max_sensor_height;
        this.coc = coc;
        this.is_auto_coc = is_auto_coc;
    }

    @Ignore
    public Camera(String list_name, String camera_name, int max_resolution_width, int max_resolution_height, int max_sensor_width, int max_sensor_height, double coc, boolean is_auto_coc) {
        this.list_name = list_name;
        this.camera_name = camera_name;
        this.max_resolution_width = max_resolution_width;
        this.max_resolution_height = max_resolution_height;
        this.max_sensor_width = max_sensor_width;
        this.max_sensor_height = max_sensor_height;
        this.coc = coc;
        this.is_auto_coc = is_auto_coc;
    }
}
```

So, with this code database could not created. Callback for create db not called. Btw, if I have autoincrement field is it possible insert custom value (for special conditions).

My logcat for this code:

> 12-04 00:54:47.536 9150-9150/ru.neverdark.photonotes I/App: onCreate: enter
>
> 12-04 00:54:47.537 9150-9150/ru.neverdark.photonotes I/AppDatabase: buildDatabase: enter
>
> 12-04 00:54:47.541 9150-9150/ru.neverdark.photonotes I/AppDatabase: buildDatabase: exit

Comment: "database not created" -- where is the code that uses any of this? `AppDatabase.getInstance()` is not going to create the database, any more than creating an instance of a `SQLiteOpenHelper` will create the database. It is only when you first try reading or writing that the database will be created.

Comment: @CommonsWare great! Problem solved

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Under the covers, by default, Room uses `SQLiteOpenHelper`, much as you might use it directly.

`SQLiteOpenHelper` does not create the database when you create the `SQLiteOpenHelper` instance. It will do so once you call `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWriteableDatabase()`.

From a Room standpoint, that means until you perform some concrete operation, such as invoking a `@Dao` method that hits the database, your database will not be created.

Comment: My usecase is that I want to access the db immediately on the home page. But the prepopulating is take a bit longer. Thus, when I query the db, I get no results as the tables are still in the process of filling up. What should I do in this case? Shall I make a dummy call to the db on the splash screen? Or is there a way to avoid this kind of lazy loading?

Comment: @PriyaSindkar: "Shall I make a dummy call to the db on the splash screen?" -- if there is data that your app is likely to use, make a call for that and cache it. Otherwise, make some cheap call (e.g., get the count of rows in some table), I guess. "Or is there a way to avoid this kind of lazy loading?" -- that would not really help you. Suppose that it takes 5 seconds to populate your database. That 5 seconds is not because of lazy-loading; it is because of the work involved. So, it will take 5 seconds whether lazy-loaded or not.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. Your answers helped a lot.

Comment: Another off-track question, if I may- Do wrongly used coroutine scopes affect the populating speed?

Comment: @PriyaSindkar: "Do wrongly used coroutine scopes affect the populating speed? " -- I do not know what Room does if it is in the middle of pre-populating the database and the coroutine scope that governs the overall piece of work gets canceled. Ideally, the pre-population work continues to completion, but I have not tested this scenario.